# Run 2 npm commands at once

Tags: node.js, shell, express, terminal, package.json

I made a MERN project, and my structure is one **backend** folder and one **frontend** folder.

So, every time I work on it I have to `cd` to **backend**, run *npm start*, then in another tab, go to **frontend** and run *npm start*.

Is it possible to do a *npm init* in the root folder, and create a *npm start* that will run both commands at once ?

I'm new to terminal.

Thanks !

Comment: Use concurrently https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this command in your terminal :

```
node frontend/index.js & node backend/index.js
```

or

```
npm start --prefix frontend/ & npm start --prefix backend/
```

You may have different paths to your files

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can do :

1- You can use concurrently(npm install -g concurrently)

---> `concurrently "command1 arg" "command2 arg`"

the most developer use these ways.And i know just these ways.

Comment: He wants to run both command from same terminal